Next.js won't update the page after changes to script
I am following the Next.js tutorial. On chapter 1, I am supposed to add "import  '@/app/ui/global.css'" to the top of the layout.tsx script. I did this and after running pnpm dev it would only show the previous version and not the newly updated page. After tinkering with visual studio code for about an hour I got it to update to have the CSS in it when I ran pnpm dev again. I thought this would be the end but once again when I made changes to the script and it did not update. This time I tried adding a black triangle to the page, I also had a log in my layout.tsx file saying "DO YOU WORK" before to check if the page updated. I removed this log when I added the triangle and its still printing "DO YOU WORK" in the console so I know the page isn't updating. Note: I do not know how I got the page to update for the global.css, I was just repeatedly opening and closing visual studio code until something worked.
I have tried restarting my computer, using npm run dev instead of pnpm dev, deleting the .next folder. None of these things have done anything to fix the issue. When I got the global.css to update I ran pnpm dev in the parent of the root directory by accident, which expectedly caused an error. After that I changed to the root directory and did pnpm run dev and it updated. However I believe that it was a coincidence since I am not able to replicate it.
